# Why particles stay suspended in the air and seems separated from the other layers of the atmosphere?

Tags: thermodynamics, atmospheric-science, air

Example: in the following image:

[image] you can see that particles are suspended at a certain height, but they don't keep floating beyond - like, a ballon (best comparassion I can make).

I wonder what are those particles and why they keep suspensed in that area.

Does the other layers of the atmosphere contains these particles?

It is possible emulate this phenomenon?

> I'm really interesed about this topic and I admit I don't know anything, but, I want to learn and understand.

Comment: They are tiny water droplets that are falling very slowly because the air drag on them prevents them from falling faster.  The force on the droplets are gravity and air drag, and for a tiny droplet with a large surface to volume ratio, the air drag is very important.

Comment: [Earthscience](https://Earthscience.stackexchange.com) might be a better place to ask. @ChetMiller Should we migrate it? (It looks like smog to me.)